How to implement an API database-connection to replace Django's functions
I have a project running in Django that handles all of my database actions through urls and views. I want to change this to Postgres and use an API that instead handles all of my database actions. This would be my first API so i'm not sure what the optimal process of designing it would be.
So far I have just initialised a new project, I want to use Typescript and express.js.
